# Mock Objects vs Test Database

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

What's the advantage of using mock objects in comparison to a static test database that has known data and using transactions to make sure nothing changes when testing against the database.

Comment: One can object that testing a database is not part of unit-test

Comment: @mathk What if he has logic in stored procedures?

Comment: @aehiilrs Then testing with both objects and a database is _still_ an integration test, not a unit test.  But both are automated tests regardless, and both may be driven with a unit-testing framework.  Now my question is, if you write tests in sql that run on a database to test stored procs on a database (on the same server), is that a unit test or an integration test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do both.  Use mock objects to test you BLL logic and then use a test database to test your DAL logic.  That way if something breaks you can easily see where the problem lies by which test fails.

Comment: wording: I presume "BLL logic" would unfold to "Business Logic Layer logic". It seems like the extra "logic" is redundant. Also, along with "Data Access Layer" these are prevalently used in Microsoft products so it would make sense to use common terms instead, when answering this Microsoft-independent question.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, using a mock will be much quicker than connecting to an external database. However the main reason is that mocks behave the same each time the test is run, which you can't guarentee with an external service like a database, which means unit tests don't fail randomly. You can also easily simulate any types of failure you want to handle with a mock object.

It's also a good idea to run integration tests against a real database however to test things like configuration and performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure that the static test db doesn't change during testing then I think static test db is better than mock objects. But, then it depends on what you want to test and the complexity of the code being tested. I would go with mock objects as they are simpler to maintain compared with a db.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you're about to write a class which doesn't exist. Maybe it's a controller. It's not something which talks straight to the database.

You have a good idea of how it ought to behave, and you know what it should be responsible for, and what it should delegate to some other service (using Single Responsibility Principle). So you write interfaces to represent the roles of the helper classes it's going to use.

Then you write an example of how you might use your class that you're about to create. If you like, you can call the example a unit test. You mock out the interactions with the helper classes. When you run the example, it fails, because you haven't written the code yet. You can now write the code to make it pass, using the interfaces of the helper classes - which you also haven't written yet.

Then you do the same with the helper classes, mocking out *their* helpers.

Eventually you'll reach a class which talks to the database. Or maybe it talks to a web service. Or perhaps the data is static, or in memory. (It doesn't matter to the original class, because your class is decoupled from this).

At this point you'll want an example to describe the behaviour of this class, too, and if it's a database connector, you'll need a database for the example.

Writing code this way produces code that's easy to use and understand, with nothing extra that isn't needed by something further up the stack. This is usually more robust than code that's easier to write. That's why we sometimes use mocks - because writing tests first using mocks helps produce good, maintainable, decoupled design.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use both of these approaches.

For unit tests you would use mocked objects. This way you can test your system in a much more fine-grained way, because you can mock every object - not only the ones that wrap the database connection. In general it is good practise to unit test every class in separation of all the dependencies. The benefits are - its is possible to test all the error handling on all levels and make sure you test all the code paths, when you get a test failure you can immediately find the cause, etc.

For integration and end-to-end tests you test big parts of the system or the whole thing. Then you would connect to the database (because this connection is part of the test). Obviously you have to ensure that the database is in a known state, etc., etc.

You will end up having much more unit tests than integration tests, so its actually quite important to make them very quick - yet another advantage of using mock objects.

Answer (score 0):

The setup for testing with a db can be arduous. If you find yourself spending more time in setting up the db, just to test some functional aspect of your business logic, then you might want to use a mock/fake.